# How to position –THIS– in a Flex-container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I'm trying to position the "register" as the picture #1... But the only thing I get is picture #2.

The pic#2 is done as we know in a flexbox, reson why is I'm making the site responsive, and the first site I did (pic#1) wasn't responsive.

I don't know if I should mix up "col-" classes to my flexbox code or what. Both pictures are tables. And the one in the flexbox is working fine when the viewport is reduced. I'm using media queries for the responsiveness, pure CSS. Not using frameworks.

How can I freely position anything in a flexbox while keeping everything responsive, if I position elements with padding and margins I won't be able positions anything else there.

[This is what I want: (not a flexbox)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTmlM.jpg)
[This is the most I can get to it: (inside the flexbox)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBy73.jpg)

** CSS code for pic# 2 (flexbox childs):**

```
      /*flex-container*/
          #header {
            position: fixed;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            background-color: #343434;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
            height: auto;
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-right: 10px;
            padding-bottom: .3%;
            padding-top: .3%;
            border-bottom: 1px solid white;
            z-index: 1000;
        }

    /*flex-childs*/
/*table*/    #login {
            margin-left: auto;
           }


 /*td*/      #users {
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
            border-radius: 1px;
            font-size: 12px;
            padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
        }

   /*td*/     #pass {
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
            border-radius: 1px;
            font-size: 12px;
            padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
        }



 /*td*/       #register {
            font-size: 17.5px;
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help with your coding problem, you will need to actually **show** us your code. Please update your question so that it shows all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: To add to what @ObsidianAge said, avoid all kind of vocabulary which can be offensive, racist or not proper to this blog.

Comment: Thanks!  I just post the code. Hope you could help!

Comment: We need the markup you use also, not enough with CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about something like this, i wrote it from scratch didn't made it to be exactly the same but i believe the structure should be sufficient

first image (to get the full responsive affect you will need to set media query on top-row and change the     `justify-content: flex-start;`)

https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/1450/

html:

```
<div class="column rows-container">
<div  class="top-row row">
<div>
  <span>Register?</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>Help Contact</span>
</div>

</div>
<div class="bottom-row row" >
  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="email">
  </div>
  <div>
     <input type="text" placeholder="password">
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

css:

```
.register-box{
  display:inline-flex;
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#111;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px; 
}
.register-box .register-title{
  margin-left:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.column{
  display:flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
}
.rows-container{
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    display:inline-flex;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#111;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.row{
  display:flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.top-row{
 flex-wrap:wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
 padding-bottom:12px;
}
.top-row span{
  padding-right:10px;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:bold;
  display:block;
  line-height:11px;
}
.bottom-row{
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  margin-right: 25px;
  margin-left:65px;
}
```

second image

https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/1448/

html:

```
<div class="register-box column">
  <div class="top-row row">
      <div>
          <span class="register">register?</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="contact">help contact </span>
      </div>
  </div>
   <div class="bottom-row row">
      <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="email">
      </div>
      <div>
       <input type="text" placeholder="password">
      </div>
      <div>
       <button>
       login
       </button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.register-box{
  background-color:#111;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
 }

.column{
  display:flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
}

.row{
  display:flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.register-box .top-row{
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  color:#fff;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  padding: 0px 18px 5px 12px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.register-box .top-row .register{
      font-weight: bold;
}
.register-box .top-row .contact{
         font-size: 14px;
         line-height:11px;
         font-weight: bold;
         display: block;
}

.register-box .bottom-row{
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  padding: 0px 18px 0px 12px;
}

.register-box .bottom-row input{
  margin-right:5px;
}
```

Comment: I can see a few things I could try, thanks!. Although, what I want is to move the register text to the left, not over the "e-mail" input... As the first image link I attached (which I did with absolute positioning). I need to make something similar work in the flex-container.

Comment: This worked really good, seems I need to play a bit more with flexbox... thanks!!

Comment: if this answer solved your problem you should accept it be clicking the V sign. Accepting answers is a nice way to motivate people providing useful answers

Comment: Just did, I'm kinda new to this site! Thanks!